# how to upsert many fields in prisma ORM

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, prisma, prisma2

How can I upsert many fields in prisma ORM with one query?

I don't want to use upsert fields one by one. Can I upsert all of them with one query?

Answer (score 19):

You can't do it right now in Prisma. There is `createMany`, `updateMany` and `deleteMany`, but no `upsertMany`. ([Docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#createmany))

The most efficient way if you need to handle lots of data would probably be something like that:

```
prisma.$transaction([
  prisma.posts.deleteMany({ where: { userId: 1 } }),
  prisma.posts.createMany({
    { id: 1, title: 'first',  userId: 1 },
    { id: 2, title: 'second', userId: 1 },
    { id: 3, title: 'third',  userId: 1 },
  }),
]);
```

So you delete existing records and then recreate them again inside of a transaction.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of retrieving the final updated state of the data than making a 3rd `prisma.posts.findMany({ where: { userId: 1 }})` call at the end of the transaction?

Comment: Would the `deleteMany` cascade and delete rows from other tables?

Comment: @devordem Depends on your setup, but yes, normally it probably would

Comment: for me, the records has so many dependedncies, i can't just delete them, else I violate so many constraints.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the database (and schema) you use, Prisma supports an optional boolean within a createMany call: `skipDuplicates`, see https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#createmany

> Do not insert records with unique fields or ID fields that already exist. Only supported by databases that support ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.

Comment: It's not what is required `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` won't update existing records. Unfortunately, this feature is not available, although it is very much in demand.

Comment: this is not what the OP is asking for i think, as skipDuplicates doesn't "update" if existing records exists, it skips them instead.

Comment: Thanks. I wish Sqlite supported this.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to `deleteMany` and then `createMany` will likely not work due to relational constraints while trying to remove records. If that's the case one of the top answers will not work for you.

### Another Option

Although there is an `updateMany` it doesn't handle an update like we would want -- it can update many records all with the same value. So unfortunately you will have to update records one-by-one.

It's too bad that the `createMany` with the `skipDuplicates` flag doesn't return the records that were created. If that was the case we could find the difference between the returned records and update the records that were not created.

#### Plan of Attack

1. Find Many
2. Update Many
3. Create Many
4. Optional: Find Many again if you need the results back

### Example

In this example assume we have a merchants table with a unique constraint on the merchant's name, so we can utilize that to update by without having something like an ID, this allows us to have the assumption that the record may or may not exist.

This doesn't feel great, the only win you are really getting is the `createMany`. You might be best to just utilize the `upsert` from prisma if you do not have many records. If you have a ton of records then maybe this route is worthwhile.

```
function async upsertMerchant(merchants: Merchant[]) {
  const merchantNames = merchants.map((merchant) => merchant.name)

  const existingMerchants = await prisma.findMany({
    where: {
      name: {
        in: merchantNames,
      },
    },
  })

  // For a quick lookup
  const existingMerchantNames = new Set(existingMerchants.map((merchant) => merchant.name))

  // This could be a reduce instead if you would like.
  // I figured this is easier to follow for most folks.
  const merchantsToCreate: Merchant[] = []

  merchants.forEach((merchant) => {
    if (existingMerchantNames.has(merchant.name)) {
      await prisma.merchant.update({
        where: {
          name: merchant.name,
        },
        data: merchant,
      })
    } else {
      merchantsToCreate.push(merchant)
    }
  })

  await prisma.merchant.createMany({
    data: merchantsToCreate,
    skipDuplicates: true, // optional, there should not be duplicates, unless other code is racing you in concurrency.
  })

  // Optional if you want all the merchants back
  // This should return all newly created and previously existing records with updated information.
  return Prisma.merchants.findMany({
    where: {
      name: {
        in: merchantNames,
      },
    },
  })
}
```

### In Conclusion

As I stated earlier, if you have a ton of records this may be more performant on the `createMany`, otherwise you're stuck updating records one-by-one. If you can `deleteMany` that is a quicker more performant approach, but likely not an option if you have relationships.

If you're not working with a ton of records it might be easiest to just loop through and utilize a Prisma `upsert`. It would most definitely result in easier to read code.